# OpenGL ES on iOS saved image has incorrect result (Black color on partially transparent edges)

Tags: ios, image-processing, opengl-es, drawing

I'm building on top of Apple's GLPaint example for an app with a drawing view. I use this to clear:

glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

This allows me to put an image behind what is being drawn, I later merge the two images, but when I save the mostly transparent image from the OpenGL context, any pixel that is partially transparent appears to blend with black. (Changing the clear color to transparent white makes it blend with white). I've tried playing with many options and haven't found a work around.

Here are two screenshots, the first is what the drawing app looks like, the 2nd is what I get when I attempt to save an image from the OpenGL context.

From screenshot:
[image: Image as seen on iOS]

From glReadPixels, being displayed in a UIImageView:
[image: Image I get from glReadPixels]

Relevant Code:

```
-(UIImage*)mergeImage:(UIImage*)image1 withImage:(UIImage*)image2{

CGSize size = image1.size;
```

// UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 1.0f);

```
[image1 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f)];
[image2 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f)];

UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


return result;
```

}

-(UIImage *) glToUIImage{

```
int imageWidth, imageHeight;

imageWidth = self.frame.size.width;
imageHeight = self.frame.size.height;

NSInteger myDataLength = imageWidth * imageHeight * 4;


// allocate array and read pixels into it.
GLubyte *buffer = (GLubyte *) malloc(myDataLength);
glReadPixels(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

// gl renders "upside down" so swap top to bottom into new array.
// there's gotta be a better way, but this works.

GLubyte *buffer2 = (GLubyte *) malloc(myDataLength);

for(int y = 0; y < imageHeight; y++){
    for(int x = 0; x < imageWidth * 4; x++){
        buffer2[((imageHeight - 1) - y) * imageWidth * 4 + x] = buffer[y * 4 * imageWidth + x];
    }
}

// make data provider with data.
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer2, myDataLength, NULL);
//CGDataProviderRef provider2 = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, white, myDataLength, NULL);

// prep the ingredients
int bitsPerComponent = 8;
int bitsPerPixel = 32;
int bytesPerRow = 4 * imageWidth;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaLast;
CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

// make the cgimage
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(imageWidth, imageHeight, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);


UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

CGImageRelease(imageRef);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(myImage, NULL, NULL, NULL);

CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
free(buffer);
free(buffer2);

return myImage;
```

}

-(UIImage *) glToUIImageOnWhite{

```
int imageWidth, imageHeight;

imageWidth = self.frame.size.width;
imageHeight = self.frame.size.height;

NSInteger myDataLength = imageWidth * imageHeight * 4;


// allocate array and read pixels into it.
GLubyte *buffer = (GLubyte *) malloc(myDataLength);
glReadPixels(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

// gl renders "upside down" so swap top to bottom into new array.
// there's gotta be a better way, but this works.

GLubyte *buffer2 = (GLubyte *) malloc(myDataLength);

GLubyte R, G, B, A;

for(int y = 0; y < imageHeight; y++){
    for(int x = 0; x < imageWidth*4; x+=4){
        R = buffer[y * 4 * imageWidth + x];
        G = buffer[y * 4 * imageWidth + x +1];
        B = buffer[y * 4 * imageWidth + x +2];
        A = buffer[y * 4 * imageWidth + x +3];

        buffer2[((imageHeight - 1) - y) * imageWidth * 4 + x]    = 255-(A-R);
        buffer2[((imageHeight - 1) - y) * imageWidth * 4 + x +1] = 255-(A-G);
        buffer2[((imageHeight - 1) - y) * imageWidth * 4 + x +2] = 255-(A-B);

        buffer2[((imageHeight - 1) - y) * imageWidth * 4 + x +3] = 255;
    }
}

// make data provider with data.
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer2, myDataLength, NULL);
//CGDataProviderRef provider2 = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, white, myDataLength, NULL);

// prep the ingredients
int bitsPerComponent = 8;
int bitsPerPixel = 32;
int bytesPerRow = 4 * imageWidth;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaLast;
CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

// make the cgimage
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(imageWidth, imageHeight, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);

UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

CGImageRelease(imageRef);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);


CGDataProviderRelease(provider);

free(buffer);
free(buffer2);

return myImage;
```

}

Comment: Can you show the code for how you are generating the screenshots?

Comment: I'm using the glToUIImage function from this page: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/20081-merging-content-of-uiimageview-and-eaglview.html

With the exception that I've added "kCGImageAlphaLast" to the bitmap info to preserve the alpha channel of the CGImage.

Comment: Interesting Discovery: Blending works fine if I change the opacity brush by passing it to glUniform4fv in the setBrushColorWithRed:Green:Blue: function.

Its only the partial transparency of the brush image itself that blends wrong o_O

Comment: You are going to need to show some code. How are you viewing and saving the screenshot?

Comment: It seems I can't made large comments, here is the relevant code, you'll have to paste it in to XCode for syntax highlighting: http://digitaldiscrepancy.com/code.txt

The first image I capture uses glToUIImageOnWhite, after that I use glToUIImage and the merge function. Even if i save a UIImage directly after glToUIImage is called it still doesn't appear right.

Comment: Relevant code with HTML syntax highlighting: http://digitaldiscrepancy.com/code.html

Comment: You should put the relevant method in the question. I suspect the method causing the issues is `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(myImage, NULL, NULL, NULL)`, this will be performing JPEG compression on the image which could be affecting the alpha components. Which image is which above? Is one the UIImage returned and the other saved to the photo album?

Comment: Both the images above are actually screenshots from the app, the one on the bottom is being displayed on a UIImageView, its not from the photo album.

Comment: Have you tried using kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast ?

Comment: AHA! That has certainly fixed the image, thank you! I did play around with that value a bit, but never tried that one. Put it as an answer and I'll check it off :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alpha regions are too dark, it is possible the color buffer has premultiplied alpha. In that case, your CGImage should be created using:

```
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast;
```